# Redux state management after refresh of page

Tags: angular, redux, store, ngrx

I am using ngrx/store in my latest angular project. But I am struggling to find a better approach in maintaining the state after the refresh of any page. I store my access_token in the store so when I refresh It doesn't maintain the token and intercept send it without token. which eventually makes it a bad request.

What to do?? Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Fellow Software Engineer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to persist your state in for example the localStorage of the browser.
You can do this by using meta reducers or in an effect.

There is also a popular library called https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage that does exact this thing.

Answer (score 1):

NGRX state is only held in memory. If you want it to persist between page refreshes Go for LocalStorage or sessionStorage.

**For Angular 5:**

`npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@5`

**Register it in your RootModule**

```
import { LocalStorageModule } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    ...
  ]
```

**Inject and use it**

```
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  constructor(protected localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

}
```

**Usage**

```
let user: User = { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };
this.localStorage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => {});
```

Note: The difference between window's LocalStorage and @ngx-pwa LocalStorage is, Data will not be visible in DEV tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should store token in Store before making requests. So you should create Token resolver where you store token in Store before you access app component which makes you sure that token is available before making requests.